# Turtlebot Dashboard Warning : robot_state_publisher

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the following warning from my turtlebot dashboard:

```
Node: /robot_state_publisher
Time: 1328731882.225292572
Severity: Warn
Location: /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-robot-model-1.6.4/debian/ros-electric-robot-model/opt/ros/electric/stacks/robot_model/kdl_parser/src/kdl_parser.cpp:treeFromUrdfModel:173
Published Topics: /rosout

The root link base_footprint has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what is causing this warning, and how to fix it?  Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12941/turtlebot-dashboard-warning-:-robot_state_publisher/) by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this should be fixed in the TurtleBot 0.9 release, please update.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aroarus](https://answers.ros.org/users/990/aroarus/) on 2012-03-28**:
I have updated to the latest packages, and I am still getting this error when I run minimal.launch